# Autowired @Service is null not everywhere

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I know that billions question with that problem, but i can't solve my one. I have app with Spring + Hibernate. Hibernate has 2 configs(for customer's and administrative databases). Customer's hibernate support multi-tenancy with DATABASE approach. Also i use Spring Security.
 It is my class for tenant id resolve:

```
@Component
public class MyTenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        User u = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        com.lspsystem.model.User us = userService.getByLogin(u.getUsername());
        return us.getCompany().getTenantId();
    }

    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's my UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public User get(Integer id) {
        return userDAO.get(id);
    }

    public boolean delete(Integer id) {
        return userDAO.delete(id);
    }

    public void update(User u) {
        userDAO.update(u);
    }

    public List<User> getAll(User u) {
        return userDAO.getAllUsers();
    }

    public User getByLogin(String login) {
        return userDAO.getByLogin(login);
    }
}
```

**My question**: Why `UserService` in `MyTenantIdResolver` is always `null`? But, for example in next class(from security) it doesn't `null`.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public User loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        com.lspsystem.model.User u = userService.getByLogin(s);
        return new User(u.getEmail(), u.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(u));
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(com.lspsystem.model.User u) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Note that UserService and MyTenantIdResolver belong to different hibernate configs.

**UPDATED**
Customer hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:customerHibernate.properties"})
public class RemoteDBHibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean(name = "customerSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean builder =
            new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    builder.setDataSource(dataSource1());
    builder.setPackagesToScan("com.lspsystem.model");
    builder.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    builder.afterPropertiesSet();

    return builder.getObject();
}

@Bean("defaultDS")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.multiTenancy", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.multiTenancy"));
    properties.put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"));
    properties.put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException{
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return txManager;
}}
```

Admin hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:adminHibernate.properties"})
public class AdminDBHibernateConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean(name = "adminSessionFactory")
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean builder =
            new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    builder.setDataSource(dataSource());
    builder.setPackagesToScan("com.lspsystem.model");
    builder.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    builder.afterPropertiesSet();

    return builder.getObject();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("admin.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException{
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return txManager;
}}
```

Web app config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver view = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    view.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    view.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    view.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return view;
}}
```

UserDAO, for example:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("adminSessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public com.lspsystem.model.User get(Integer id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    User u = (User)session.load(User.class, id);
    return u;
}

public User getByLogin(String login) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email");
    q.setParameter("email", login);
    User u = (User)q.list().get(0);
    return u;
}}
```

Comment: Provide your config classes/files.

Comment: Yes your config file please. Anyhow just an idea : how a single service can have two persistence conf in the same time ? (If I understood your situation exposal)

Comment: My configs added.

Comment: Does Hibernate create and manage the instance of MyTenantIdResolver itself in this case? I never used that functionality, but given that you configure the classname as a hibernate property, i highly suspect it is the case.

Comment: I find solution without using UserService,  And all work fine. So I think there is no problem in resolver...

Answer (score 2):

This can not be true! `@Autowire` will force the field to be non-null. So the only case to have `userService=null` is when `MyTenantIdentifierResolver` is not a spring bean!

Make the instance of `MyTenantIdentifierResolver` to a spring-bean.

Comment: Sorry, you mean add @Bean annotation?

Comment: @ArtemP. No, the class is configured well. Search for the spring-configuration to find out why the class is not being used as a spring-bean.